# mouse cursor default while selecting text?

Tags: css, cursor

How can be the mouse cursor kept default while select text.
     i use :`-webkit-user-select: none;`.

thanks.

Comment: You dont want people to be able to select? Is that the question?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: like here in http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-ui table of content

Comment: It's still absolutely unclear what you want. You want the mouse cursor to look like something, somewhere, under some circumstances?

Comment: yes but hover does not work while selecting

Answer (score 18):

Use the following css style on the element containing your text

```
cursor: default;
```

Comment: +1 if you add [the MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor#Keyword%20values#:~:text=default) to give some more explanation on what `cursor: default;` does

Answer (score -5):

Use

```
cursor: pointer;
```

for getting a cursor like the one one which you get when hovered on a link

Comment: I'm not asking for hover